# Is there a built-in function to convert time zones

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are loading data from Hana to Snowflake. In Hana, we have time stored in different formats like CET, UTC+3, UTC+4, BRAZIL,AUSACT etc. In hana, we have a function that can convert the timestamp into these various time zones. How do we do it in Snowflake?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html

Comment: I saw that, but did not see equivalent parameters for AUSACT, BRAZIL

Comment: Snowflake uses IANA timezones https://www.iana.org/time-zones. There's a list on Wikipedia too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones. I'm not aware of any mappings from what Hana uses to IANA timezones, but such a mapping may exist somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The process I followed is as below

1. Create a table to map the HANA and SNOWFLAKE format

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE HANA_SF_CONVERT(HANA_FORMAT VARCHAR,SF_FORMAT VARCHAR);
```

```
insert into HANA_SF_CONVERT(HANA_FORMAT,SF_FORMAT) VALUES('CET','Africa/Ceuta');
insert into HANA_SF_CONVERT(HANA_FORMAT,SF_FORMAT) VALUES('AUSACT','Australia/ACT');
```

2. Created a function as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function hana_sf_convert(hana_fmt string,sf_tz string,date_val timestamp) 
    returns timestamp
    as 
    $$
        select convert_timezone((select SF_FORMAT from 
        HANA_SF_CONVERT where HANA_FORMAT = hana_fmt ),sf_tz ,date_val )
    $$
    ;
```

Finally, can query as below

```
select hana_sf_convert('CET','America/Los_Angeles',date_val::timestamp_ntz) as time, date_val from <table>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Greg nailed this.

- To [CONVERT_TIMEZONE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html) - Yes!
- To convert_time to/from the Timezones that you like to refer to - No

So that answers the question if there is built it functions.

Can you build your own function that uses SQL or JavaScript to covert from the reference/name space you have, to values Snowflake supports sure.

Comment: I finally wrote a UDF to do this